# Mysql returns connection error 500 instead executing die function

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I'm developing an application and try to debug any errors.

At first I've created a simple MySql connection script, see below:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","AwesomePassword", "todo");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Now, I'm trying to debug this code by changing the credentials. In stead of the 'die' function is triggerd, I get "localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500".

[image]

In my log file of Apache2 I get following message: "::1 - - [11/Mar/2024:11:07:16 +0100] "GET /imap/Connection/connect.php HTTP/1.1" 500 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

When the credentials are correct, I get the connection and the pages are working correctly. It seems to be a mysql issue instead of php.

My question: How can I ensure that the 'die' function is executed instead of the HTTP ERROR 500?

With kind regards

Comment: You should check what your PHP error log has to say, rather than the web server access log. Guessing you're probably dealing with an uncaught exception error.

Comment: Hi CBroe, thanks for your quick response
I get following error: [11-Mar-2024 11:12:33 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'rot'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/imap/Connection/connect.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/imap/Connection/connect.php(6): mysqli->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/imap/Connection/connect.php on line 6

Comment: You want to explicitly instruct mysqli to _not_ throw exceptions then, see duplicate.  Or you just rewrite the code, so that it actually catches exceptions, and handle the error that way.

Comment: Yes, I just did it. Now I'm caching the exeption and it works. On weird way, the 'die' function doesn't work.